# Python value difference in dataframe by group key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame

```
name   value
A       2
A       4
A       5
A       7
A       8
B       3
B       4
B       8
C       1
C       3
C       5
```

And I want to get the value differences based on each name
like this

```
name   value   dif
A       2      0
A       4      2
A       5      1
A       7      2
A       8      1
B       3      0
B       4      1
B       8      4
C       1      0
C       3      2
C       5      2
```

Can anyone show me the easiest way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) to compute the difference between consecutive rows per grouped object. Optionally, filling missing values( first row in every group) by 0 and casting them finally as integers.

```
df['dif'] = df.groupby('name')['value'].diff().fillna(0).astype(int)
df
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much , one more question, If I want to sort the value first ,then calculate the difference, how can I do that?

Comment: Assuming you want to sort them in ascending order, you can include `df.sort_values(['value'], inplace=True)` as a prior step. If you intend to sort them otherwise, you could do `df.sort_values(['value'], ascending=False, inplace=True)`. This will sort them in descending order. In this case, the differences obtained would be negative.